# The mystery of the silent string (server receiving null string from Android Client)

Tags: java, android, client

I'm trying to get my android to talk to my computer, and I've almost got it. I can send strings over the internet to my computer and all, but there's just one problem: when my computer reads the strings they're null!

Here's the code for the client:

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4, message, port;
TextView con;
Button send;
InetAddress inet;
Socket s;
OutputStream out;
PrintWriter output;
int sip;
int rport;
byte[] ip;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ip1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIP1);
    ip2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIP2);
    ip3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIP3);
    ip4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIP4);
    port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPort);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    con = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCon);
    ip = new byte[4];

    send.setOnClickListener(this);    }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.bSend:

        try{
            rport = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            con.setText(e.toString());
            break;
        }

        try{
            sip = Integer.parseInt(ip4.getText().toString());
            sip = (sip << 8) + Integer.parseInt(ip3.getText().toString());
            sip = (sip << 8) + Integer.parseInt(ip2.getText().toString());
            sip = (sip << 8) + Integer.parseInt(ip1.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            con.setText(e.toString());
            break;
        }

        ip[0] = (byte)(0xff & sip);
        ip[1] = (byte)(0xff & (sip >> 8));
        ip[2] = (byte)(0xff & (sip >> 16));
        ip[3] = (byte)(0xff & (sip >> 24));

        try {
            inet = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            s = new Socket(inet, rport);
            out = s.getOutputStream();
            output = new PrintWriter(out);
            output.println(message.getText().toString());
            con.setText("Message Sent");
            s.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            con.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            con.setText(e.toString());
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

And here's the code for the Server:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Boolean end = false;
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4331);
        while(!end){
                //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); //Autoflush
                String st = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(""+st);
                s.close();     
         }
         ss.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

EDIT: I found the problem; originally i wasn't using the emulator to test my code i was using my actual android because i couldn't get the wifi to work on the emulator (it was a simple fix) so when ran the code on my emulator it works, no null string; but when ran on my real android it returns null, there's only one reason i could think of that would cause this to happen, the sdk I'm using doesn't match my androids os version (its older) could this be the reason or am i wrong?

EDIT: I got it, it turns out i just needed to install some of the api 10 packages from androids sdk manager works like a charm now :)

Comment: Are you using your actual device on wifi or over 3g/4g? Many carriers block non standard ports, sometimes on their network, sometimes on the device itself

Comment: actual wifi i bought the Samsung galaxy media player it doesn't have phone capabilities

Answer (score 0):

The null strings are just a way for `readline` to signalize that the input stream has ended, following your call to `close` on the client.

Your code is basically supposed to work.  Add more logging and disable the Nagle algorithm for faster (easier) debugging by calling `setTcpNoDelay` on the client socket before you connect.

Comment: I tried calling setTcpNoDelay and I'm still receiving null on the server side, any other reason this could be happening?

Comment: @user1483936 - Please tell us the exact timing on client side at which the server receives the null.  Add logging and sleep calls or use a debugger to determine that.